# Coalesce terminal output strings into one string with Python

Tags: python, shell, selenium, terminal, command

I am trying to fetch the output of the `fortune` command and send it to web-based WhatsApp. I am able to fetch the output from the `fortune` command, but when I send it to WhatsApp, the `fortune` output is outputted as separate lines/messages. How do I make them into one and send it as a single message? Thanks.

```
fortune_list = ["(?i)art","(?i)comp","(?i)cookie","(?i)drugs","(?i)education","(?i)ethnic","(?i)food"]

for i in range(len(fortune_list)):
    if re.search(re.compile(fortune_list[i]),reply):
        cmd = ['fortune', fortune_list_reply[i]]
        output = subprocess.Popen( cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
        print output
        input_box[1].send_keys(output)
        time.sleep(1)
        b.find_element_by_class_name('send-container').click()
```

The output on the terminal (`print output`)

[image]

The ouput sent on WhatsApp as seperate messages.

[image]

Desired output as a single message.

[image]

***Edit 1 :*** Using `repr` : Coalesces the strings but with these characters. Using regex replace to replace the characters isn't working.

`"XXXI:\n\tThe optimum committee has no members.\nXXXII:\n\tHiring consultants to conduct studies can be an excellent means of\n\tturning problems into gold -- your problems into their gold.\nXXXIII:\n\tFools rush in where incumbents fear to tread.\nXXXIV:\n\tThe process of competitively selecting contractors to perform work\n\tis based on a system of rewards and penalties, all distributed\n\trandomly.\nXXXV:\n\tThe weaker the data available upon which to base one's conclusion,\n\tthe greater the precision which should be quoted in order to give\n\tthe data authenticity.\n\t\t-- Norman Augustine\n"`

***Edit 2:*** Answer added.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem to work. Infact I tried to reduce the whitespaces of all lengths to one using replace. Replace doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It's not working. I tried `repr` and It did make it as a single string but with \n,\t and all those. After that I tried replacing \n \t using regex but isn't working.

Comment: Yeah. I have updated.

Comment: Same output. No changes. How is it not replacing the characters? after all its an output string from a command.

Comment: beats me. I'll have to test that on my machine. maybe a special encoding? BTW python 2 or python 3?

Comment: Python 2.7..Quite surprised by this.

Comment: can you post full code (containing `fortune_list_reply` array) ? and also `reply`. I cannot reproduce without it.

Comment: Yeah.. Here http://pastebin.com/eBPZZLSX. Thanks !

Comment: Tried almost everything, searched places for solutions but nothing seems to work. Any positive signs?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand where the big sentences are coming from? When I run your code I always get an empty output.

Comment: Big sentences ? Its the output of fortune command. Did you input the category name after it displays?

Comment: yes; but I don"t have the data files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To coalesce the output strings of terminal into one, split the output at new lines and store them in a list.

```
sentence = ""
cmd = ['fortune', fortune_list_reply[i]]
output = subprocess.Popen( cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()[0]
output = output.split('\n')
for string in output:
    string = string.split("\t")                                     
    for substring in string:
        if len(substring) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            sentence = sentence + " " + substring
```